# Nginx Reverse proxy and latency

Tags: nginx, amazon-elb, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I have an application running behind nginx, sitting behind AWS ELB.  The server runs about 30 instances of the application.

Part of the application is processing uploaded image files sent via HTTP POST in multipart/form-data type requests.

It works but during peak load latency goes up to about 120 seconds (asmeasured by the ELB load balancer).  The uploads typically take about 2 to 7 seconds, and during normal load the end-user response time is about the same.

Running more instances of the application causes the server to run out of memory, so at this point the solution is to run additional EC2 instances during peak load only.

However the Application processing time of a request is in the region of 0.2 seconds, even during peak load.  It would seem that Nginx as reverse proxy should be able to cache the application requests and only forward them to an application worker once the entire payload is received.  But it seems nginx is only handling, or possibly receiving, one request at a time from ELB, per application worker.

Is there a way to get the end-user response time closer to the actual request time shown below:

```
197.229.3.57 - [24/Jan/2019:11:13:51 +0000] "POST /v1/schools/69a787fc-3fde-46b1-a258-f0a1954c9abe/children/cf14ac79-9e33-434c-b5e2-8cf51d856e6f/mediamessages HTTP/1.1" RC=202 Sz=388787/388160/574 "-" Times=0.254/0.254/6.252 "client 1.1.35" zip="-" "127.0.0.1:7087"

197.229.3.68 - [24/Jan/2019:11:14:15 +0000] "POST /v1/schools/69a787fc-3fde-46b1-a258-f0a1954c9abe/children/16ced012-1c7d-41f2-969a-21ad28c80361/mediamessages HTTP/1.1" RC=202 Sz=316182/315555/574 "-" Times=0.235/0.235/3.435 "client 1.1.35" zip="-" "127.0.0.1:5085"

197.229.3.68 - [24/Jan/2019:11:14:26 +0000] "POST /v1/schools/69a787fc-3fde-46b1-a258-f0a1954c9abe/children/df5b4919-b3a9-495a-95b7-40c4b9abf523/mediamessages HTTP/1.1" RC=202 Sz=335840/335213/574 "-" Times=0.241/0.241/2.241 "client 1.1.35" zip="-" "127.0.0.1:7086"

197.229.3.68 - [24/Jan/2019:11:14:41 +0000] "POST /v1/schools/69a787fc-3fde-46b1-a258-f0a1954c9abe/children/16666420-34b3-4582-95dc-001972eb6b43/mediamessages HTTP/1.1" RC=202 Sz=229735/229108/574 "-" Times=0.216/0.216/3.956 "client 1.1.35" zip="-" "127.0.0.1:5086"
```

Within the log the values for Times=aaaaa/bbbb/cccc 
Where:
 -  aaaa is upstream_header_time
 -  bbbb is upstream_response_time
 -  cccc is request_time

Relevant parts of nginx.conf file:

```
worker_processes 1;
#errors_log logs/error.log notice;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    server_tokens off;

    log_format echo_log_format '$http_x_forwarded_for - [$time_local] '
                           '"$request" RC=$status Sz=$request_length/$http_content_length/$body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                           'Times=$upstream_header_time/$upstream_response_time/$request_time '
                           '"$http_user_agent" zip="$gzip_ratio" "$upstream_addr"' ;

    sendfile on;

    client_body_temp_path /spool/nginx/client_temp 1 2;
    #client_body_in_file_only on;
    client_body_in_file_only clean;

    real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;
    set_real_ip_from 0.0.0.0/0;

    keepalive_timeout 10m;
    client_body_timeout 20m;
    client_header_timeout 10m;
    send_timeout 10m;
    proxy_read_timeout 600;

    client_max_body_size 300M;

    gzip              on;
    gzip_http_version 1.0;
    gzip_proxied      any;
    gzip_min_length   500;
    gzip_disable      "MSIE [1-6]\.";
    gzip_types        text/plain text/xml text/css
                      text/comma-separated-values
                      text/javascript
                      application/x-javascript
                      application/atom+xml;

    # Expires map
    map $sent_http_content_type $expires {
        default                    max;
        text/html                  epoch;
        text/css                   max;
        application/javascript     max;
        ~image/                    max;
    }

    map $status $invalid {
        ~^400  1;
        default 0;
    }

    map $request $logpostdata {
        ~devices 1;
        default 0;
    }

    map $request $multimedia {
        ~multimedia 1;
        default 0;
    }

    # ELB HEALTH CHECK
    server {
        # Running port
        listen 80;
        location /ping {
            access_log off;
            return 200 "pong";
            add_header Content-Type text/plain;
        }
    }

    upstream prod_api_workers {
        server 127.0.0.1:5081;
        server 127.0.0.1:5082;
        server 127.0.0.1:5083;
        server 127.0.0.1:5084;
        server 127.0.0.1:5085;
        server 127.0.0.1:5086;
        server 127.0.0.1:5087;
        server 127.0.0.1:5088;
        server 127.0.0.1:5089;

        # NOTE port 6081 is in use by nginx
        server 127.0.0.1:6082;
        server 127.0.0.1:6083;
        server 127.0.0.1:6084;
        server 127.0.0.1:6085;
        server 127.0.0.1:6086;
        server 127.0.0.1:6087;
        server 127.0.0.1:6088;
        server 127.0.0.1:6089;

        server 127.0.0.1:7081;
        server 127.0.0.1:7082;
        server 127.0.0.1:7083;
        server 127.0.0.1:7084;
        server 127.0.0.1:7085;
        server 127.0.0.1:7086;
        server 127.0.0.1:7087;
        server 127.0.0.1:7088;
        server 127.0.0.1:7089;
    }



    # RESERVE PROXY FOR PROD (test)
    server {
        access_log /var/log/nginx/testapi_access.log echo_log_format;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/testapi_error.log;
        listen 6081;
        server_name _;

        client_max_body_size 0;
        location / {
            #proxy_redirect     off;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $http_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   Host      $http_host;
            proxy_pass http://prod_api_workers;
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you're using a *reverse* proxy? As far as I can see, the only way to shorten the time between cccc and bbbb is to kick the proxy out as much as possible. It can be done, depending on how you serve your files of course.
nginx serves files directly, only using caching, quite well these days.
I would check if you can do the proxy within a vlan at AWS. But if you can't serve from AWS directly, perhaps change to using haproxy instead.

Comment: As described in the problem I'm serving application instances not files.

Comment: @TheTahaan Even so, have you ever tried NGINX Unit? It works just fine for me with app instances!